# convert a columns of strings in dataframe into very large integer in R

Tags: r, dplyr, gmp

I have numeric values stored in a string column named "*hst*" in a "*bd*" data frame of 1,636,626 rows, but to perform arithmetic operations, I need to convert the *hst* column to very large integers to preserve all the numbers.

I tried the `as.bigz()` function from the *gmp* package, it works for a unit value but not for the whole column.

```
bd <- bd %>% mutate_at(vars(c(hst)), list(~gmp::as.bigz(.,mod = NA))
```

here is the error I got:

> Error: Problem with the `hst` entry of `mutate()`. x The `hst` input
> cannot be recycled to size 1636626. i The `hst` input is
> `(structure(function (..., .x = ..1, .y = ..2, . = ..1) ...`. i The
> `hst` input must be of size 1636626 or 1, not 19669620.

the "*bd*" data frame looks like this:

```
id    hst
A1    155836976724791034470038871285935636480 
A2    55836976724791053359504802764516491263
B1    55836977111335639448316742086388875264      
A3    55836977111354982261430576153184174079
C2    55836926053814030414548020414090575872     
C4    55836926053833373227661854480885874687
B2    55836926013959368196946057541906857984
B4    55836926013959368215392801615616409599
C3    55836976724870256890155492454040600576
```

Comment: If you want to perform calculations, can't you use as.numeric()?

Comment: as.numeric does not keep all the digits of the number in question, therefore the calculations are distorted

Comment: Works as matrix calculation as.bigz(matrix[,2])*2